# query to select data from DB based on a particular day and count how many rows are there?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have Db which has data of an year...so I need a query to select data from based on a date(particularly yesterday's) and count how many are in this.....

Help please!

It has a column with name "created" where all the date & time are present.

code used:

```
//$thirty_reg = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM user WHERE user.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()");
//$num_thirty=mysql_num_rows($thirty_reg);

//echo $num_thirty;
```

Comment: OK. What's the problem with the query you've written already?

Comment: I tried to calculate the list of rows like a hundered times....always gives a warning that mysql_num_rows is a resource that must be 1

Comment: So there's a problem with your code? You could post it and see if someone can fix it.

Comment: Try adding a call to mysql_error to see what the database is returning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day) < DateColumn
        and DateColumn < curdate()
```

Comment: Dude...you rock!!!!! Thanks a lot been dying since one day for this. Thanks a lot man :)

Will accept your answer in a few mins...have some time limit presently.

Comment: What do I do if i need data for past 30 days.....Is it just this simple:  

select  *
from    YourTable
where   date_sub(concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00'), interval 30 day) < DateColumn
        and DateColumn < concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00')

Comment: Yeah, that should work.  There's no substitute for testing tho :)

Comment: one quick question though: If I need to select for one particular month how do I write in the above manner?



Like if I want to display for this current month only....it has to display from the start of this month till the current date.



Is this correct for current month data?



 select * from YourTable where date_sub(concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00'), interval Date('j') day) < DateColumn and DateColumn < concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00')

Comment: Yes, `date_sub(concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00'), interval day(curdate()) day)` should work, or simpler: `date_format(now() ,'%Y-%m-01')`

Comment: Why `concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00')` and not just `curdate()`?

Comment: @ypercube: You're right, I thought `curdate()` was a synonym for `now()`, but it returns only the datepart of `now()`

Answer (score 0):

To fetch result set:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data_date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

To fetch count of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE data_date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: One day ago is not yesterday :)  Gotta strip the time part

Comment: @Andomar would agree if it's a datetime column. Does it matter for date column?

Comment: @njk: For a datecolumn it doesn't matter, but the question says "It has a column with name "created" where all the date & time are present."